# How to get the current position of the object moving from top to down when user taps on it in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I need an idea from ur side as when the objects moving from top to bottom when I tap on one of the object I need the current position of that object.Can anyone please suggest me the idea to get this.

thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a code since I don't have an iPhone or an iPhone SDK, but I can provide a suggestion.

Perhaps you have four variables:

```
int top-left-x: 5;
int top-left-y: 10;
int width: 30;
int height: 40;
```

Use top-left-y to keep track of object's position. Once a user taps an object that is moving down, check the conditions to make sure the tap is well within an object:

```
if((tap.x > top-left-x && tap.x < top-left-x + width) &&
   (tap.y > top-left-y && tap.y < top-left-y + height))
{
    // The user taps an object
}
```

In plain English, if the object's top-left position is (5,30) and bottom-right position is (35,70) and the user tapped within the bounds of an object, an object has been tapped. How I get the bottom-right position is by subtracting 5 from 35 and I get 30, which is the object's width. Subtract 30 from 70 and that gives me 40 pixels of height.

I'm not good at translating programming language to plain English but I hope I can be of help.